# Illegal Character "|" at Google Maps API V2 request

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am using the Google API V2 in Android. If I want to get the route from pointA to pointB but I want to make it through pointC and pointD, [Google says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) that the request should be:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=pointA&destination=pointB&waypoints=pointC|pointD
```

However, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 191: blablabla (it is because | character)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
        at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
        at mcd0n3ld.roadcheckpoints.ToolsMap$JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(ToolsMap.java:216)
        [some more but not interesting...]
```

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Kind regards,
Raúl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Encode your parameters with the [URL Encoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

```
String params = "pointC|pointD";
try {
     params = URLEncoder.encode(params, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

then concat

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=pointA&destination=pointB&waypoints="+params;
```

Comment: It worked! At first I was trying to URLEncode the whole URL but that did not work. Only worked doing what you said, that is URLEncoding the problematic part. Thank you very much! :D